Why does curve_fit not fit 3d curve
I'm trying to fit a multiveriable curve to the function y**2*(y**2/4 - a*y/3 + b/2) - x**2*(x**2/4 - a*x/3 + b/2) but it seams that curve_fit doesn't fit to the generated data. The pcov values are all inf and the a and b outputs remain the same as the guesses.
Here is my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def func(X, a, b):
    x,y = X
    return y**2*(y**2/4 - a*y/3 + b/2) - x**2*(x**2/4 - a*x/3 + b/2)


# some artificially noisy data to fit

x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
a = 6
b = 9
z = func((x,y), a, b)


# initial guesses for a,b:

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, [x,y], z, p0=[10,8])

print(popt)
print(pcov)
print("a = ",popt[0] ," +/- ", np.sqrt(pcov[0,0]))
print("b = ",popt[1] ," +/- ", np.sqrt(pcov[1,1]))


#surface plot

ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
x_data = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
y_data = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_data,y_data)


Z = func((X,Y), popt[0], popt[1])
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()

The code works for other functions but not this one.

When you increase the dimensionnality, you also have to sample correctly in all dimension. In your MCVE you are only sampling over a single line instead of sampling in the plane.
The following sampling spreads over the plane:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

def model(x, a, b):
    return x[1] ** 2 *(x[1] ** 2 / 4 - a * x[1] / 3 + b / 2) - x[0] ** 2 *(x[0] ** 2 / 4 - a * x[0] / 3 + b / 2)

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

a = 6
b = 9
x = (X.ravel(), Y.ravel())

z = model(x, a, b)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, z, p0=[10,8])
#(array([6., 9.]),
# array([[6.78893023e-33, 2.09471226e-32],
#        [2.09471226e-32, 6.64942515e-32]]))

And fits properly.
The following figure shows your sampling and the plane sampling with surface:

Also notice, than your original sampling lies exactly on single isopleth:


Ah ok, I didnt realise is had a set sampling pattern. Thanks!

When I run your code, I get the following warning
 line23: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, [x,y], z, p0=[10,8])

So, it seems there is nothing wrong with your function, but the initial guess values that might seem to be asymptotic in this case. I tried with other values of p0 and it works fine. Do you have any special reason of using these values.

Out of curiosity, would you mind to share some parameters that make the fit works with initial dataset provided by the OP.
